# EJS escaping in gruntfile

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have the following code in my gruntfile:

```
'string-replace': {
  inline: {
    files: {
      'entity/templates/': 'entity/templates/*', 
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: /Article/g,
        replacement: '<%= entityName %>'
      }, {
        pattern: /article/g,
        replacement: '<%= _.slugify(entityName) %>'
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to replace the word "Article" in a few files with an expression. I want this expression to be printed as so in the replaced file, but now it's evaluated instead.

How do I escape the code?

I'm using https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace but I think that the problem lies in how grunt evaluates expressions, right?

The error message is the following:

> Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (entityName is not defined). Use --force to continue.

Comment: Have you tried the basic escape character: `\`? I honestly don't know if it will work, but you can try. So maybe this: `'\<%= entityName %\>'`?

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work though. I came up with the solution below instead, which works. If you find a better way, please add them to this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now solved it by doing this:

```
'string-replace': {
  inline: {
    files: {
      'entity/templates/': 'entity/templates/*', 
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: /Article/g,
        replacement: '<%= entityName ENDTAG'
      }, {
        pattern: /article/g,
        replacement: '<%= _.slugify(entityName) ENDTAG'
      }, {
        pattern: /ENDTAG/g,
        replacement: '%>'
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to insert jsp termination tags, also '%>' but I was using grunt-replace. Same solution works but it would be better if we could make this a 1 line soluton

Comment: Agreeed. I have not found a solution other than this yet though.